# What are some of the different perspectives toward the formation of moral commitments or vows?

Tags: ethics, moral-agency

By experience, I have come to find that in order to cultivate a lifestyle that is pertinent to a subjective sense of purpose, it is necessary to make moral commitments which constrain certain behaviours but focus action on those which are deemed of better value, in spite of natural behavioural tendencies.

I would define a vow as a consensual rule, standard or constraint placed upon the behaviour of the individual so as to focus action toward the maximisation of a particular subjective standard of value.

e.g. marriage vows as being the constraints perceived as necessary to uphold a culture's concept of the trust between a married couple, consensually (in most cultures) taken by both partners.

What would be some good texts for a modern take on the nature of vows, historiography of vow-making or criticism of the idea of vows and other such behavioural constructions?

Comment: Generally it's very rare and not required for contemporary philosophers to take vows for their proposed theories due to their innate speculative nature anyway. You could see many such texts in religious texts such as those investigating Vinaya in Buddhism...

Comment: this is a sociology or anthropology question, not for this forum

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda its an ethics question, which makes it a philosophy question ergo appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @DoubleKnot Okay, Thanks for the tip.